# Conversion of Malli schema to JSON schema?

Tags: json, clojure, malli

How do I convert the Malli schema to JSON schema?
I have a malli schema  in edn format & it needs to be converted to JSON schema.

Comment: https://github.com/metosin/malli#json-schema

Comment: This is with respect to a schema defined inope.clj right? What if I have a schema-config.edn file else where. How do I covert then?

Comment: @Blaze Can you share how you are doing it?

Comment: I want to do it using a mapper-key extracted from an end file. Which has different maps for different DTOs.